# vim interpret argument with colon(s) as filename:line:column

Tags: vim

Is it possible to configure VIM in a such way that if I type

```
vim filename:123:89
```

it opens file `filename` goes to line 123 and column 89?

If not through VIM maybe with a hack for the shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how to skip to the column, but I've wanted the same feature for ages, so I just hacked up the "jump to line" functionality. In your `.bashrc`, set

```
VIM=$(which vim)

function vim {
    local args
    IFS=':' read -a args <<< "$1"
    "$VIM" "${args[0]}" +0"${args[1]}"
}
```

This splits the argument to Vim by `:`, then constructs a command line of the form

```
vim <filename> +0<line>
```

The `+0` is a hack to make sure the default line number is zero.

(If you're not using Bash, you can adapt this into a script and put it in your path, or translate it to your favorite shell language. To edit `filename:with:colons`, use `$VIM`.)

Comment: You can jump to line & column with `$ vim -c 'norm!123G89|' filename`.

Comment: Use `$ vim filename -c "37norm 13|"` to jump to column 13 of line 37 or `filename`.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work by replacing the last line in function `vim` by the lines `if [ -z "${args[1]}" ]; then args[1]="1"; fi` and `"$VIM" "${args[0]}" -c "norm!${args[1]}G0${args[2]}|"`. Suggestions how to do it in a better way are welcome.

Comment: It would probably be easier to use `command vim` instead of `$VIM` to launch the vim in the path. The command builtin suppresses function lookup.

Answer (score 9):

You can install the [file-line](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2184) plugin to open a file to the line and column specified after the filename. ([github mirror](https://github.com/bogado/file-line))

From the Readme on github

> When you open a `file:line`, for instance when coping and pasting from
>   an error from your compiler vim tries to open a file with a colon in
>   its name.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> vim index.html:20 
> vim app/models/user.rb:1337
> ```
>
> With this little script in your plugins folder if the stuff after the colon is a number and a file exists with the name especified before the colon vim will open this file and take you to the line you wished in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using the file-line plugin, but it has a few open issues, and breaks some other vim plugins. So I went fishing for a better solution. Here it is:

```
function vim() {
        local first="$1"
        case $first in
                *:*)
                        shift
                        command vim ${first%%:*} +0${first##*:} $@
                        ;;
                *)
                        command vim $@
                        ;;
        esac
}
```

Limitations:

- bash only
- Only parses first argument, whereas vim +X parses the first *file* argument. A more complex version could easily be made with proper command line parsing.

Advantages:

- doesn't break other vim plugins
- you could easily use $EDITOR and use this with emacs for instance.
- compared to Fred's answer it doesn't use IFS/read to parse the argument but uses bash parameter expansion.
- also sends in the remaining argument, which might occasionally be necessary.

Comment: Just curious how does file line break other plugins. I've been using it for a long time and haven't noticed anything. So far this is the only thing I see better about this. file line even handles `:e` which I find important if you never close vim

Comment: @FDinoff : look at the issues, for instance this one: https://github.com/bogado/file-line/issues/62